# Escape Lucene special chars in full-text query

Tags: neo4j

I'm using a new feature from neo4j 3.5.4: full-text search indexes. And I need to get the node with a "name" field where value contains special chars like *?- and so on.

I already used default re.escape function to escape term string.

The result query looks like:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(
"property_search_index", 
"name:\?\?\?\.\.\.\/\/\/\*\*\*~"
) YIELD node AS property, score
```

where input term before escaping looks like this: `???...///***`

The query returns next error message:

```
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: 
Invalid input '?': expected '\', ''', '"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', 
UTF16 or UTF32 (line 1, column 68 (offset: 67))
```

So, the question is how to escape this string properly? or is it a neo4j bug?

Comment: I’ve never used neo4j, but I have done a bit with Lucene.  Did you try enclosing the search string in quotes? E.g “name:\”\?…

Comment: ```CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes( "property_search_index", "name:\"\?\?\?\.\.\.\/\/\/\*\*\*~\"") YIELD node AS property, score```  
- the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So the root of the issue was in backslashes. Since lucene query is put in double quotes, we have to duplicate backslashes. So the query should look like:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes(
"property_search_index", 
"name:\\?\\?\\?\\.\\.\\.\\/\\/\\/\\*\\*\\*~"
) YIELD node AS property, score
```

If you wrap this query into apoc function, you have to duplicate backslashes.